# jquery not appending to ul

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get something in PHP using $.post in jquery to append to the `<ul>`, but the output is blank, how do I append the `li` data to the `ul`?

my `PHP`

```
$queryStmt = 'SELECT test_part_id FROM test_part WHERE test_id=:sqlId';
        $queryPrepare = $dba_connect->prepare($queryStmt);
        $queryPrepare->execute(array(':sqlId'=>$_POST['testId']));
        $queryResult = $queryPrepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $queryPrepare->closeCursor();

        $tempString = '';
        $tempNum = 1;

        foreach($queryResult as $row) {
            $tempString .= "<li><span class=''></span>
                                            <button id='".$row['test_part_id']."' 
                                                          name='".$row['test_part_id']."' 
                                                            type='button' 
                                                            class='listPartOfExam'>".
                                    "Part ".$tempNum."</button></li>";
            $tempNum++;
        }

        $tempString .= "<li><span class='red'> </span> button id='btnTeachLogout' name='btnTeachLogout' type='button'>Logout</button></li> ";

        echo $tempString;
```

my `Jquery`

```
$.post(
    '../php/teacherfunction.php',
    {'functions':'generatePartsButton','testId':localStorage.inTestid},
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#ulEditExamPartsMenu ul').append(data);
    }
);
```

and the html code:

```
<div id='divEditTestMainMenu' hidden=''>
    <ul id='ulEditExamPartsMenu' class='coolHandLuke'>
    </ul>
</div>

I use the alert above to see what is inside the data, and it is correct:

<li><span class=''></span>

    <button id='TC-201402150304203041_1' name='TC-201402150304203041_1'
        type='button' class='listPartOfExam'>Part 1</button></li>
<li><span class=''></span>

    <button id='TC-201402150304203041_2' name='TC-201402150304203041_2'
        type='button' class='listPartOfExam'>Part 2</button></li>
<li><span class=''></span>

    <button id='TC-201402150304203041_3' name='TC-201402150304203041_3'
        type='button' class='listPartOfExam'>Part 3</button></li>
<li><span class='red'> </span> button id='btnTeachLogout'
    name='btnTeachLogout' type='button'>Logout
    </button></li>
```

Comment: The `<` is missing in your button element, what you write with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ulEditExamPartsMenu` is the id of the `ul` so

```
$('#ulEditExamPartsMenul').append(data);
```

Your selector `#ulEditExamPartsMenu ul` is looking for a `ul` element which is a descendant of an element with id `ulEditExamPartsMenu`, such an element does not exists so nothing is getting appended.

Answer (score 2):

this is looking for `ul` in this element `ulEditExamPartsMenu`, which itself is the `ul`:

```
$('#ulEditExamPartsMenu ul').append(data);
```

so the change should have to be done like:

```
$('#ulEditExamPartsMenu').append(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace  this line

```
$('#ulEditExamPartsMenu ul').append(data);
```

with ,

`$('#ulEditExamPartsMenu').append(data);`

or

`$('ul#ulEditExamPartsMenu').append(data);`

reason is **ulEditExamPartsMenu** is ID of `ul` itself

Also u missed `<` in below line after `</span>` close

```
$tempString .= "<li><span class='red'> </span> button id='btnTeachLogout' name='btnTeachLogout' type='button'>Logout</button></li> ";
```